# Confused with realization of mathematical formula

Tags: c#, formula

Could you please help me with realization of mathematical formula in C#? Here it is:

R(t)=∑((x[i]-M)*(x[i+t]-M))

∑ goes from i=0 to N-t

M = const, t =[0,...,n], x is the vector with random data.

My implementation doesn't work correct and I don't know where the mistake is( I know, that I want you to do it for me, but I don't have anyone else to ask for help( Your help will be very appreciated! Thank you!

There is my code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < tvect.Lenght; i++)
        {
            sum[i] = 0;
            t = tvect[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < (N - t); j++)
            {
                sum[i] = sum[i] + (data[j] - M) * (data[j + t] - M);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
float[] R(int[] t)
{ 
  float[] sum = new float[t.length];
  for (j=0;j<t.length;j++)
  {
    sum[j] = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N-t[j]; i++)
    {
       sum[j] += (x[i]-M)*(x[i+t[j]]-M);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I thought so too...but `t =[0,...,n]` from OP

Comment: t is a parameter that has to be in that range... I have undestood that

Comment: Thanks, but t is a vector... It's like t contains x coordinates and I need to calculate y coordinates by this formula.

Comment: It's obviously... There is answer below by kaveman with the realization.

Comment: that's not the formula you writed... not so obvius... :P

Comment: Strange... There was hard to write the formula, besides there is my poor knowledge of English and so on... Ok, anyway thanks for help!

Comment: I have modified it... if t is a vector, it returns a vector?

Comment: Yes, it returns the vector of sums: t contains x, sum = R(t) contatins y. 
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
float sum = 0.0;
for(int j = 0; j < t.Length; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N - t[j]; i++) {
        sum += (x[i]-M)*(x[i+t[j]]-M);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's almost the same as I did, and why it doesn't work correct? I need to check it carefully one more time...